# How to get Woocommerce emails to retrieve a higher resolution product image

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added the following code to my *functions.php* file to get product images showing in emails:

```
function w3p_add_image_to_wc_emails( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;
    $args['image_size'] = array( 400, 400);
    return $args;
}
```

This works, but it retrieves a version of the product image that's only 150px by 150px, and simply enlarges it to 400px by 400px. The resulting image is noticeably blurry, [as you can see from this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHqzL.jpg).

Bigger versions exist on my db, including a 400x400 version (and all standard Woocommerce and Wordpress image sizes), but it seems to default to the 150x150 version. Is there any way I can force the use of a bigger image size for emails?

Comment: you can set the image size to `full` / `woocommerce_thumbnail` / `woocommerce_single` / `large`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this counts as 'fixed', but I got around the issue by setting the default minimum size (thumbnail) to 400 x 400 through Wordpress and regenerating thumbnails. This might affect other parts of your site, but it worked for me.